# Check for memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments

Hi please tell me if there is any memory leak in my code or not..
I am solving my memory leaks in my app but confused here will it create a memory leak?

```
     NSMutableArray *dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if(condition)
{
        [dataArray addObject:[appDelegate selectFromDatabase:x]];//returning an autoreleased array
}
else
{
dataArray=[appDelegate selectFromDatabase:a];
}
     //use dataArray

        [dataArray release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This code will leak memory.** You reassign dataArray without releasing the old value. Do the assignment through a generated property and the old value will be released first.

```
else
{
    dataArray=[appDelegate selectFromDatabase:a];
}
```

You could also restructure your code to avoid creating the array unless you really need it:

```
if (condition)
{
    // Create array here
}
else
{
    // get array from other place
}
```

Comment: Good pick up. You can also choose to initialise your NSMutableArray with a convenience/autoreleased method such as [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems]

Comment: @Rog - Fair point, but probably easier to understand the code if the array is only created IF it is needed. I've updated my answer

Comment: @Ranjeet Sajwan - No problems mate

Answer (score 0):

You can use Instruments to help you search for memory leaks.

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/